# Storing list with objects in a state for future use in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I am getting a response like this from my axios response and I want to store the same in a state to pass it further.

[image]

Please help me how I store this in a state. I am very new to react.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Can you post what code you've tried?  That image of the results is really hard to see.  Can you maybe copy/paste the contents of that here?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by setting your state variable to something like this:

```
const Component = () => {
   let [items, setItems] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('https://someurl.com')
      .then(data => {
          setItems(data)
      })
   }, [])
}
```

In your render function, you can then access the items array normally. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey amit still stuck in the same prob can you please help me over Google meet.. I'll be always thankful.. Please.

Comment: Hey Anurag, sure. Please send me a note at amit.maraj@gmail.com and we can set up a meet time.

Answer (score 1):

**first import useState from react**
and then do something like this with the response you are getting.

```
    import react, {useState} from 'react'
        const App = () => {
        const [data,setData} = useState([])
}
```

**And inside the function that triggers the add event**

```
setData(res.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the response in the state, first you need to create a state:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState([]);
```

Next, you need to use `setValue` to put your response in the state:

```
setValue(API_RESPONSE)
```

So React will render this change and you can print `value` to see what value this const has.